# jQuery get select option id and change hidden input value

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a select list. Each option also contains a dynamic id, which I need to capture and then use that to change a hidden input's value. So basically take the selected options id and change the value of a hidden input value.

My select and hidden input look like:

```
<select name="item_options" id="size">
<option value="20030" id="Universal">Universal (20030)</option>
<option value="4545456" id="Medium">Medium (4545456)</option>
<option value="15447" id="Large">Large (15447)</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="item_options_name" value="Universal" id="changevalue" />
```

I had done some jQuery to capture the selected option's id, but I can't figure out how to use it to change my input's value.

Comment: I'm dizzy, what do you want to store in the hidden input?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$('#size').change(function(){
   var id = $(this).find(':selected')[0].id;
   $('#changevalue').val(id);
})
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('select[name=item_options]').change(function(){
    $('input[name=item_options_name]').val($(this).val());
};
```

Or you can use ID selectors:

```
$('#size').change(function(){
    $('#changevalue').val($(this).val());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#selectboxsize').change(function() {

    var id = $(this).find(':selected')[0].id;

    $('#getchangevalue').val(id);

});

</script>




<select name="item_options" id="selectboxsize">

    <option value="20030" id="Universal">Universal (20030)</option>

    <option value="4545456" id="Medium">Medium (4545456)</option>

    <option value="15447" id="Large">Large (15447)</option>

</select>

<input type="hidden" name="item_options_name" value="Universal" id="getchangevalue" />
```