# Replace select element for input text on option selection

Tags: jquery, list, select, text, input

How can I change a select list for an input text when a specific option is selected using jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get select option id and change hidden input value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810718/jquery-get-select-option-id-and-change-hidden-input-value)

Comment: I've already seen an example here on stackoverflow using the jQuery selector replaceWith but I just can't find it!

Answer (score 2):

```
<select onchange="if($(this).val()==2)$(this).replaceWith($('<input/>'))">
  <option>1
  <option>2
  <option>2
</select>
```